# Why is passing a variable by reference slower than defining it globally?

Tags: c++, performance

Given this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

typedef unsigned long long T;

namespace Benchmark
{
    T a, b;
    inline void L_Add() { a += b; b += a; }
    inline void Unroll_10() { L_Add(); L_Add(); L_Add(); L_Add(); L_Add(); L_Add(); L_Add(); L_Add(); L_Add(); L_Add(); }
    inline void Unroll_100() { Unroll_10(); Unroll_10(); Unroll_10(); Unroll_10(); Unroll_10(); Unroll_10(); Unroll_10(); Unroll_10(); Unroll_10(); Unroll_10(); }
    inline void Unroll_1000(T& a_, T& b_)
    {
        a = a_; b = b_;
        Unroll_100(); Unroll_100(); Unroll_100(); Unroll_100(); Unroll_100(); Unroll_100(); Unroll_100(); Unroll_100(); Unroll_100(); Unroll_100();
        a_ = a; b_ = b;
    }
};

inline void L_Add(T& a, T& b) { a += b; b += a; }
inline void Unroll_10(T& a, T& b) { L_Add(a, b); L_Add(a, b); L_Add(a, b); L_Add(a, b); L_Add(a, b); L_Add(a, b); L_Add(a, b); L_Add(a, b); L_Add(a, b); L_Add(a, b); }
inline void Unroll_100(T& a, T& b) { Unroll_10(a, b); Unroll_10(a, b); Unroll_10(a, b); Unroll_10(a, b); Unroll_10(a, b); Unroll_10(a, b); Unroll_10(a, b); Unroll_10(a, b); Unroll_10(a, b); Unroll_10(a, b); }
inline void Unroll_1000(T& a, T& b) { Unroll_100(a, b); Unroll_100(a, b); Unroll_100(a, b); Unroll_100(a, b); Unroll_100(a, b); Unroll_100(a, b); Unroll_100(a, b); Unroll_100(a, b); Unroll_100(a, b); Unroll_100(a, b); }

int main()
{
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point StartTime, EndTime;
    T a = 3;
    T b = 5;
    StartTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i)
        Benchmark::Unroll_1000(a, b);
    EndTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << a << " : " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(EndTime - StartTime).count() / 2000.0 << "ns" << std::endl;

    a = 3;
    b = 5;
    StartTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i)
        Unroll_1000(a, b);
    EndTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << a << " : " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(EndTime - StartTime).count() / 2000.0 << "ns" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And this output:

```
12646046898197897264 : 0.3875ns
12646046898197897264 : 2.253ns
```

I was wondering why the disassembly of "Benchmark::Unroll_1000(a, b)" is:

```
add rax,rcx  
add rcx,rax
```

whereas the disassembly of "Unroll_1000(a, b)" is:

```
mov rax,qword ptr [rdx]  
add qword ptr [rcx],rax  
mov rax,qword ptr [rcx]  
add qword ptr [rdx],rax
```

As of my understanding they should produce the same code. Can someone enlight me? And how can I achieve the same performance as "Benchmark::Unroll_1000(a, b)" without the global variable?

Comment: What optimization settings did you use?

Comment: - Interesting username "PanicSheep" - Are you Welsh?

Comment: @EdHeal Why should sheeps be scared of Welsh? Are you Welsh? :-P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a global variable: The compiler knows at compile time where the variable will lie, and can use the value directly. Additionally, your compiler has seen that you use a lot that variable and has assigned it to a register, so there are no load/write operations to RAM (that is the real timesaver).

Passing a value by reference: The method is passed a pointer to the real location of the variable. It has to dereference it and perform the operation. Also, the extra operations may mean that the variable gets a location in memory so it must be loaded/downloaded.

In your example maybe the compiler could be smart enough to produce the same code since it always uses the same actual values, but generally it cannot assume that the compiled code will be called (*linked*) always from the same method, so the generated code does the things the "slow way".

Comment: In short: it is way easier to the compiler to find that you are using the same two variables over and over by using them as global ones.

Comment: +1 for pointing that the pass by ref requires performing the operation from memory. Try to remove the `&`'s from the second version and see how fast it becomes.

Comment: It's not the memory access that's the problem. The problem is that the compiler doesn't know whether a and b are the same variable or not. If they are the same, then a += b; changes both a and b (because they are the same). So if the compiler doesn't know this, then after assigning a += b; it _must_ store the value for a back to memory and _must_ read the value for b from memory again. With global variables, the compiler can read a, read b, do ten times 2 adds, and store a and b instead of reading/writing each pair 20 times.